# bigfoot and footmisc do not work well together with "multiple" option

Tags: footnotes, footmisc, bigfoot

I would like the footnotes from the example to appear comma-separated where they are referenced in the text. The "multiple" option of footmisc should be able to do this, but it does not work.
How can I make it work? Am I loading the packages wrongly?

thanks
james

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{R}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N}

\begin{document}
First sentence.\footnoteR{Here is a footnote.}\footnoteR{Here is another footnote.}\footnoteN{And another one.}\footnoteN{And moe.} And another one.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that `footmisc` can cope with new footnote types defined with `bigfoot` commands.

Answer (score 3):

The [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) package does handle this correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.5\textwidth,
  paperheight=12\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}[2012/07/07] % v0.2d
% the `dont-mess-around' option disables additional kerning
% and punctuation switching.
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{R}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N}

\begin{document}
First sentence.\footnoteR{Here is a footnote.}\footnoteR{Here is another footnote.}%
\footnoteN{And another one.}\footnoteN{And moe.} And another one.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I will try to install this package to my Latex installation on OS X and try it out. Would be great if it works!