# Markerless footnote which is page-wide in twocolumn document

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I'm using this code to create markerless footnotes in LaTeX ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker)):

```
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
```

Furthermore I'm using the `footmisc` package for footnote style (options `hang,stable`), the `fnpct` package for typesetting multiple footnotemarks (as of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/bigfoot-and-footmisc-do-not-work-well-together-with-multiple-option) question) and the `bigfoot` package for multiple concurrent footnotes. The `bigfoot` package is used with the option `ruled` and I declare:

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
```

I use the code below to fix the vertical spacing between footnotes ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.text.tex/28U19WDYYVk)):

```
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{%
      \bgroup
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
          \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
        \else
          \@makefnmark
        \fi
      }%
      \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
      \rightmargin\z@
      \linewidth \columnwidth
      \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
      \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
      \footnotesize
      \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
      \leavevmode
      \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
      \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
      #1\strut\par\egroup %inserted \strut\par
  }

\def\FN@commonending{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \iffalse  \FN@specific\FN@masterinsert\@makefntext\fi
  \@makefnendbox
  %\ifx\FN@boxtype\vbox\@finalstrut\strutbox \else \unskip \fi
%removed
  \FN@colorstackfinish
  \color@endgroup
  \egroup
  \global\advance\FN@id\@ne
  \FN@slotxdef\FN@masterslot{\number\FN@id}%
  \ifhbox\z@
    \global\setbox\FN@tempbox\copy\z@
    \setbox\tw@\@makefnvbox{\unhbox\FN@tempbox}%
    \ht\z@\dimexpr\ht\tw@+\dp\tw@-\FN@masterslot sp\relax
  \else
    \ht\z@\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@-\FN@masterslot sp\relax
  \fi
  \wd\z@\dimen@
  \dp\z@\FN@masterslot sp\relax
  \MFL@insert\FN@masterinsert{\nointerlineskip\box\z@}%
  \marks\FN@slave{\number\FN@id}%
  \MFL@endminipage
  \FN@colorstackegroup
}
\makeatother
```

Furthermore I use this code

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand{\extrafootnoterule}{\hrule height 0.2pt \vspace{5pt}}
```

to have a larger rule between text and first type of footnotes and a thinner rule between different types of footnotes.

As an example I have uploaded a source file [here](http://pastebin.com/gh9zR7MU), the resulting `pdf` file would look like this:

[image: Example]

Note that three different types of footnotes that are all set in one single column. I use the markerless footnotes for annotations, for example for long equations which don't fit in a column (in the twocolumn layout). Therefore I'd be best if the markerless version of my footnotes would stretch and be as wide as a footnote in `onecolumn` whereas `\footnote` and `footnoteB` should still be set on a per-column basis (and thus be as wide as `\columnwidth`.

Is there a way to achive this? A **markerless footnote, that is set in onecolumn mode, where the "normal" footnote is still set in twocolumn**?

Comment: This is probably quite unrelated to what you _want_ to do, but this might go into the right direction at what you _aim_ to do. I would use marginnotes to explain things. You can have them with and without markers. Both `memoir` and `tufte-latex` have a nice support.

Comment: Your source file does not compile as posted with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, giving the error `Undefined control sequence` for `\FN@masterslot`.  Without a minimal working example that compiles, it's hard to do anything for you.  If your example requires some particular engine, you should mention that in your question.  That said, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211816/pagewide-single-column-footnote-in-double-column-document has some ideas that you might be able to tailor to your needs.